# Remove $modal effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want a simple HTML form showing user and password inputs, now form is showing up in modal box using bootstrap. I am good in java but my hands are tight on javascript and angularjs, bootstraps etc.

**Code1**

```
$scope.modalShown = false;
    var showLoginDialog = function() {
        if(!$scope.modalShown){
            $scope.modalShown = true;
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl : 'templates/login.html',
                controller : "LoginCtrl",
                backdrop : 'static',
            });

            modalInstance.result.then(function() {
                $scope.modalShown = false;
            });
        }
    };
```

other code from where the values are passing.

**code2**

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', [ '$scope', '$state', '$modalInstance' , '$window', 'Auth',
    function($scope, $state, $modalInstance, $window, Auth ) {
        $scope.credentials = {};
        $scope.loginForm = {};
        $scope.error = false;

        //when the form is submitted
        $scope.submit = function() {
            $scope.submitted = true;
            if (!$scope.loginForm.$invalid) {
                $scope.login($scope.credentials);
            } else {
                $scope.error = true;
                return;
            }
        };

        //Performs the login function, by sending a requeora to the server with the Auth service
        $scope.login = function(credentials) {
            $scope.error = false;
            Auth.login(credentials, function(user) {
                //success function
                $modalInstance.close();
                $state.go('home');
            }, function(err) {
                console.log("error");
                $scope.error = true;
            });
```

code1 is written in the maincontroller of angular app where its triggering the modal box with user and password inputs getting credentials from login.js

Comment: It's kind of confusing what exactly you want to do. Do you want to not use $modal at all? Do you want to show a modal without any special effects?

Comment: Yeah i don't want to use $modal at all.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to indicate exactly what your code does now, what you want the code to do, and what you've tried so far to get it working.